# Getting ID from Google's datastore using Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Go struct:

```
type Foo struct{
  Name: string
  Age: int
}
```

I am able to save and retrieve Foos in datastore.
So I may edit a Foo, I want to get the ID that datastore assigns a Foo, to use in an anchor.
I verified that IDs are assigned using Google's datastore dashboard, but how do I get the ID off of a retrieved Foo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Golang GAE - intID in struct for mustache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956342/golang-gae-intid-in-struct-for-mustache)

Comment: I'm a little confused. In order to retrieve Foo, you must have had the ID at some point. Are you wondering if the ID is also stored along with the Go struct somewhere?

Comment: I don't need any IDs if I do a query for all of them, or if I do a query like give me the Foo with name="me".

Comment: The answer is when "GetAll" is called, it returns []*Keys and err, then iterate over the keys and make a "viewmodel" of the struct that has id as a field and set it.

Comment: @bmw0128 Please add that (and a code example if possible) as the answer in order to help anyone else who may have he same problem.

Comment: I would recommend using the encoded string of the key rather than the ID for passing it around: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key.Encode . This method also stores data about the keys parent, which you'll need to perform a Get. Even if you don't have a parent set on keys now, you may find the need to do so later for strong consistency: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore

Answer (score -1):

`GetAll` returns the keys along with any error.

```
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &foos)
```

`keys` is an array of `datastore.Key`